# Buttons lose their functionality after enabling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to keep the button disabled until the user selects a value through the radio buttons. But the buttons dont work when they are enabled. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  var prev_minutes = undefined;
  var prev_seconds = undefined;
  var timeUpdate;


 //These couple of lines enables the buttons but they lose their functionality.
 // $("#start_pause_resume").prop("disabled", true);
 // $("#reset").prop("disabled", true);

  $("input:radio").change(function() {
    $("#start_pause_resume").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#reset").prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $("#start_pause_resume").button().click(function() {

    if ($(this).text() == "Start") {
      $(this).html("Pause");
      updateTime(0, 0);
      $("input[name='times']").attr("disabled", true);
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Pause") {
      clearInterval(timeUpdate);
      $(this).html("Resume");
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Resume") {

      prev_minutes = parseInt($("#minutes").html());
      prev_seconds = parseInt($("#seconds").html());

      updateTime(prev_minutes, prev_seconds);

      $(this).html("Pause");
    }
  });

  $("#reset").button().click(function() {
    if (timeUpdate) clearInterval(timeUpdate);
    $("input[name='times']").attr("disabled", false);
    setStopwatch(0, 0);
    $("#start_pause_resume").html("Start");
  });
```

I want to make it such that the buttons are disabled until a value is selected from radio buttons and after clicking the button, the radio buttons are disabled. I dont understand why the above doesnt work. Please help.
Here is the html code

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="10">10</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="20">20</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="30">30</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="40">40</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="50">50</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="60">60</label>

  <div id="controls">
    <button id="start_pause_resume">Start</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: `$("#start_pause_resume").button()` what's `button()` method..? are you using any plugins..? Also please share the html css etc required to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
$("#start_pause_resume").button().click(function() {
```

with

```
$("#start_pause_resume").click(function() {
```

Comment: Removing button() works, thankx. But why wasnt it working with button()?

Comment: Because .buitton() is not a valid method of a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

You can't select button like `.button()` its not a jQuery method to select buttons.

You can select them like;

```
$(":button")
```

or in your case;

```
$("#start_pause_resume:button").click(function() {
```

For more please check jQuery reference **[here](https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)**.

Comment: *".button() its not a jQuery method to select buttons"* - you just assumed that OP wants to select buttons. What if he wants to create fancy buttons..? `.button()` will become a jQuery method when the right plugin is added.

Comment: @TJ `$("#start_pause_resume").button().click(function() {` makes me think that and he didn't mentioned about any plugin in the question as well. I 100% agree with you there could be a plugin for that.